# QR code that redirects to android market

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to generate a QR code that activates the Android market application and within that application opens a specific application such as "pocket chess for android".
is it possible to do that?
and if its possible, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy.

1. Find your app on Market `https://market.android.com/details?id=kobi.chess`
2. Use any QR encoder to encode the link. For example you can use [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/chart/infographics/docs/overview.html):
   `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://market.android.com/details?id=kobi.chess`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's, you must know the link for the application in the Market.
When you've that link, you must encode it in QR (a lot of sites can help you: [A small search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=qr%20generator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)).
The mobile phone can detect automaticaly the link and he opens the browser.